# JVM is not get killed on OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I'm using `JDK 1.8.0_u66` on which `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` option is not yet available. So I ended up in setting `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"`

Okay I wrote the following simple application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    while (true) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try{
                        condition.await();
                    } catch (Exception e){}
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The application fails with the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
unable to create new native thread
```

in a split second, but it does not get killed as I expected since I set up the option `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"`.

I guess that killing the JVM is done in a separate `Thread` but it is not possible to create one since the limit is reached already. So the application silently keeps working in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Start allocating `long[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` in `main()` and see if it works in main thread. It's hard to tell what's going on since you must be using an ancient JVM if `+XX:CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` is not available.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki JVM1.8.0_u66

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Would it crash on some newer version of JDK?

Comment: Are you sure of your application? I hope you did not catch Trowable instead of Exception which would lead to this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely affected by [JDK-8155004](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155004) which makes the `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` and related options fail to run when `OutOfMemoryError` is caused by thread creation.

Your current approach works well when `OutOfMemoryError` is caused by insufficient heap memory. You can test this with below code and `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"` option. It exits the JVM `1.8.0_191` (closest I have to your version):

```
public static void main() {
  Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  });
  t.start(); // to prevent natural JVM exit when main dies

  ArrayList<Long[]> retain = new ArrayList<>();
  while (true) {
    Long[] arr = new Long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    retain.add(arr);
  }
}
```

Comment: @SomeName The problem is present in `1.8.0_191`. I guess you would have to check it with specific JVM version to see if it works as the bug is unresolved.